# C# generic object cannot be added to list of that generic type

Tags: c#, generics, collections, casting

Sorry if question name wasn't that explicit, but I couln't find a better one...

Here's my problem :

I have a class :

```
public class WatchableVariable<T>{
  ...
}
```

A Container Class :

```
public class CommonWatchableVariableContainer
{
  private List<WatchableVariable<IComparable>> Watchables;

  ...

  public void Add<T>(string name) where T : IComparable
  {
    WatchableVariable<T> test = new WatchableVariable<T>(name);
    Watchables.Add(test);
  }

  ...
}
```

And have a strange error  :

[image]

Which, IMO, should work since i'm applying a "IComparable" constraint on my generic type.

could someone point me out where I might have messed up ?

**EDIT** : I already tried to implement IComparable on Class WatchableVariable which resulted in the exact same error :/

```
public class WatchableVariable<T> : ObservableObject where T : IComparable
  { ... }
```

**EDIT 2** : While trying to implement the solution proposed by canton7, I realized I may be blocked.

Here's the interface I created :

```
public interface IWatchableVariable<out T>
{
  T Variable { get; set; }
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve :

```
double dVar1 = process();
double dVar2 = process();
double dVar3 = process();

bool bVar1 = process();

CommonWatchableVariableContainer container = new CommonWatchableVariableContainer ();
container.Add<bool>("myTrackedVariable_1");
container.Add<double>("myTrackedVariable_2");

container["myTrackedVariable_1"].Variable = dVar1; //Variable would be a property of type T (which would be double in this case)
container["myTrackedVariable_2"].Variable = bVar1;

foreach(IWatchableVariable WV in container){
  process(WV);
}

container.Remove("myTrackedVariable_1");
```

Does this make things clearer ?

Comment: This code does not make sense to me. What you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: In `class WatchableVariable<T>` you don't have a constraint like `where T : IComparable`.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria - Did you test if that was correct? No, would be the answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, but I didn't say that this fixes the problem. I simply noted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collection is a `List<WatchableVariable<IComparable>>`. You're trying to add a `WatchableVariable<T>` to it.

This is not allowed, because of the rules of generic variance. Let's pretend that your `WatchableVariable<T>` class defined this method:

```
public class WatchableVariable<T>
{
    public void Set(T value);
}
```

If you've got a `WatchableVariable<Foo>`, you can call `watchableVariable.Set(new Foo())`, but *not* `watchableVariable.Set((IComparable)foo)`. That makes sense.

Take that to your situation, and someone could call `Add<Foo>("")`, so `Watchables` contains a `WatchableVariable<Foo>`. They then access `Watchables[0]`, which gives them a `WatchableVariable<IComparable>`, and call `Set((IComparable)bar)`. This would be unsafe, as we previously said that a `WatchableVariable<Foo>`'s `Set(T value)` method will only accept a `Foo`, but we've just given it any old `IComparable`!

The way around this is using covariance, which is only available on interfaces.

First, we declare a generic interface, and we promise that you can only ever take `T`'s out of it, and never put them in, using `out T`:

```
public interface IWatchableVariable<out T>
{
    // The compiler stops you from defining any methods which accept a T
}

public class WatchableVariable<T> : IWatchableVariable<T>
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you can write:

```
private List<IWatchableVariable<IComparable>> Watchables;
```

And everything will work.

(A similar thing is available using contravariance and `in T`, but that isn't applicable to your situation).

---

**In response to your Edit 2**

Your edit contains the comment

```
// Variable would be a property of type T (which would be double in this case)
```

That's a run-time assertion. You will have to define your interface like this:

```
public interface IWatchableVariable<out T>
{
    object Variable { get; set; }
}
```

Since `Variable` isn't of type `T`, this is allowed. Then your `WatchableVariable<T>` class will have to do a run-time cast, to make sure that `Variable` was set to a compatible type. You can use an explicit interface implementation to make this a bit neater.

```
public class WatchableVariable<T>
{
    public T Variable { get; set; }

    object IWatchableVariable<T>.Variable
    {
        get => Variable;
        set => Variable = (T)value;
    }
}
```

You can make this slightly neater by doing something like:

```
public interface IWatchableVariable<out T>
{
    T Variable { get; }
    void SetVariable(object value);
}

public class WatchableVariable<T> : IWatchableVariable<T>
{
    public T Variable { get; set; }
    public void SetVariable(object value)
    {
        Variable = (T)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Daaaamn, I tried using covariance but thought it'd be a loss of time :/ I'll try that out right away ;-)

Comment: @AxelSamyn please remember to accept an answer which solves your problem

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it took me some time to deal with your answer x) I added an EDIT 2 in my question, I think I cannot SET data into my list with your solution since I cannot write this   :  public interface IWatchableVariable<out T>
  {
    T Variable { get; set; }
  } ... I'd like to be allowed to set that Variable

Comment: That is correct. As my question explains, that would be unsafe. You could construct a `WatchableVariable<Foo>`, and then call `watchableVariable.Variable = "test"`. That would obviously be incorrect, but it would be allowed.

Comment: Indeed :/ Would there be a safe way to acheive this?

Comment: I've updated my answer. There's a way you can get the compiler to accept it, but you're now relying on a runtime check

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but to make that work you should: declare your type with an `IComparable` constraint.

```
public class WatchableVariable<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public WatchableVariable(string name) { }
}
```

Then make your second class generic with the same constraint.

```
public class CommonWatchableVariableContainer<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private List<WatchableVariable<T>> Watchables;

    public void Add(string name)
    {
        var test = new WatchableVariable<T>(name);
        Watchables.Add(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the OP wants a single common `CommonWatchableVariableContainer` and not one per `T`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Maybe, really I'm not sure about what the OP try to achieve.