get a list that can store a class that has different generic T
I'm trying to get a list that can store a DataColumn that takes in generic T but each DataColumn can have a different type:
public class DataColumn<T>
{
    private string columnName;
    private List<T> values;
    public readonly Type dataType;

    public DataColumn(string columnName, Type dataType)
    {
        this.columnName = columnName;
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

public class DataTable
{
    private List<DataColumn<object>> columns;
    public bool AddColumn<T>(string name)
    {
        //DataColumn<T> column = new(name, typeof(T));
        DataColumn<object> column = new(name, typeof(T));
        columns.Add(column);
        length++;
        return true;
    }
}

The commented line doesn't work.
Why can the object not store generic type T?
Why is DataColumn<T> different from DataColumn<object>?
Why can type T not evaluate to object?
One solution is to create an interface IDataColumn and the list would store it:
public interface IDataColumn
    {
        Type GetType();
        bool Add(dynamic value);
        object GetValue(int index);
    }

public class DataColumn<T> : IDataColumn{...}

While it does solve the issue, this creates another inconvenience for accessing the attributes. I could create getters but it would return either dynamic or object and not the type that the table stores values as because the interface doesn't know it. But I was told to avoid the use of these as they can lead to unsafe checks.
How do I solve this?

Have you seen this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572258/c-sharp-generic-object-cannot-be-added-to-list-of-that-generic-type

Yes I have but I was really confused with the example it gives with foo. And for the solution using covariance, I don't fully get it but using  would mean I can't modify any attribute with T or passes in T, but I think I would need to modify attribute with T in my class.

Start with https://dotnetfiddle.net/crT8tm .

Honestly though - why do this at all? Why not use Dapper and proper strongly typed objects?

From the dotnetfiddle, I see that it's very similar to the way I used interface in my attempted solution but instead, it's an abstract class? I'm not seeing any difference aside from a few syntax differences?
From what I read, Dapper is used for ORM, right? I'm not really mapping this to an actual database but rather just building a mock of in-memory database, so that wouldn't help with it.

The generic parameter is part of the type, so DataColumn<T> and DataColumn<object> is mostly unrelated as far as the type system is concerned. There is variance to convert generic types, but it has specific rules that need to be followed. But you will probably get better advice if you explain what it is you are trying to do. If you just want an in memory database there is such a provider for EF.

I see. I will try using convariance later tonight . But what I was trying to do is just try to imitate an in-memory database, and also code my own b-tree indexing later. Maybe its possible to build my indexing on top of the EFC managed memory (assuming it doens't already offer it) but it sounds a lot more complicated.

I'm not seeing any difference aside from a few syntax differences? The difference is that using DataColumn<object> is basically pointless. What benefit does it give you? If everything is inside a DataColumn<object> (which in your model it will need to be if stored in a List<T>) then all benefits of generics gets thrown out. My model gives you the ability to have a specific type in the generic class (e.g. DataColumn<int>), but also a means to get the value in the base class, regardless of whether it is DataColumn<int> or DataColumn<string> etc etc.

but rather just building a mock of in-memory database, Then why use DataColumn at all? Return a List<WhateverYourConcreteTypeIs>. This is a classic XY problem. You've come at the problem with a solution. But the solution you have chosen is not a good one.

Ah I think I just understood difference between classes and types. If I'm understanding correctly, even though the generic T instance at runtime may inherit from object, their type are not the same. (type Object != type T unless T is somehow type Object but other cases, it's different)
And to @mjwills , by difference in syntax, I was comparing to storing in interface List<DataColumn<IDataColumn>> which acts in a similar way to the abstract class in yours and offer the same functionality.

I think there are a few merits to the DataColumn class. I did consider just using a list before, but I thought when I add more features like constraints, say unique constraint, the responsibility should be separated to the column instead leaving all the functions to the DataTable to take care of it.

You are modelling data access on the way that ADO.NET works. That way is not modern. Smarter ways, like how ORMs work, is what you should be imitating instead.

offer the same functionality. It offers the same functionality but only be neutering the power of generics. If DataColumn<IDataColumn> is going to give you the same capabilites of DataColumn then - well generics aren't helping. My approach thus gives you the best of both worlds - the abstract type is clear on what is common, and the inheriting generic type is clear on the difference. But either way - I think (as I said earlier) you are attacking the problem the wrong way altogether.

type Object != type T Correct.

You have a variance problem. You can usually fix variance problems by adding more generic parameters, or by adding more types. I'd recommend adding a non-generic based type class DataColumn{} class DataColumn<T>:DataColumn{} then you can use the non generic list; List<DataColumn>.

The solution could look like this:
public abstract class DataColumnBase { }

public class DataColumn<T> : DataColumnBase {
    private string columnName;
    private System.Collections.Generic.List<T> values;
    public DataColumn(string columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }
    // ...
}

public class DataTable {
    private System.Collections.Generic.List<DataColumnBase> columns =
        new();
    public bool AddColumn<T>(string name) {
        DataColumn<T> column = new(name);
        columns.Add(column);
        return true;
    }
}

Eventually, you may still need to do the type case, but only on values. Ideally, you can get rid of type casts completely. To do so, you can avoid using arbitrary value types, two. Then you can add an abstract base class ValueBase for all value types or an interface IValue to be implemented by all these types, use this base type of interface in the generic constraints of T, and never cast values to their runtime types. Instead, operate with those values only through their IValue or ValueBase members overridden in all runtime value classes. That would be a pure OOP approach.
Now, I'll try to answer your questions.

Why can the object not store generic type T?

You can, in the form of System.Type. Yes, System.Type can represent generic types, too, but a generic type cannot be a type of any object. You can store an object of the System.Type only for the object types you can define, and it won't make sense in the case of your code. A generic type is not a type in the following sense: you cannot create an object of this type. You can only instantiate a generic type to make a complete type out of it, and only then create an object of this complete type. Don't mess things up: you can get a runtype type of any object using object.GetType(), but this runtime type is not a generic type.

Why is DataColumn<T> different from DataColumn<object>?

DataColumn<object> can be a real object in memory. DataColumn<T> cannot be an object, because this is just a declaration based on the generic type parameter T. It can become an object only when a generic method or class is instantiated with one of the complete types based on T.

Why can type T not evaluate to object?

Because there are no objects of T in nature. T is not a type, it is a generic type parameter, a formal parameter. It becomes a type only after the instantiation of the generic type when an actual type parameter substitutes T.
